# Squared Brownian motion with drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am trying to work out on the way to express the following process $Z_t$ as a form of squared Bessel process, if it is at all possible. I have a Brownian motion, $W_t$, with a drift $\alpha_t$ and $Z_t$ is defined by
$$Z_t=\int_0^td(W_s+\alpha_s)^2$$

---

Addendum after Kurt G.'s comment

---

I can write
$$dZ_{t}=dt+2|W_{t}+\alpha_{t}|\mathrm{sgn}(W_{t}+\alpha_{t})d(W_{t}+\alpha_{t})$$
and introduce the BM
$$B_t=\int_0^t\mathrm{sgn}(W_{s}+\alpha_{s})d(W_{s}+\alpha_{s})$$
and then I am done with
$$dZ_{t}=dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}dB_{t},$$
which is the expected result. Is it correct?

---

Now, I am a bit lost. What can you say about the starting point of this process and the non-centrality parameter of the non-central chi-squared between 0 and the horizon $t$? Is it $\int_0^t \alpha^2_{s}ds$, $\alpha^2_{t}$ or $\alpha^2_{0}$?

---

Idea after Kurt G.'s comment

---

Can I say, starting from $W_t$ under the measure $\mathbb P$, that there is another process $W'_t$ defined as:
$$dW'_t=dW_t+\alpha'_tdt$$
such that $W'_t$ is a BM under a different measure $\mathbb P'$? Then, $Z_t$ is defined under $\mathbb P'$ as $Z_{t}=W'_t{}^2$. Obviously,
$$dZ_{t}=dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}dB'_t$$
where $B'_t$ is a new BM (martingale with mean 0 and variance $t$) defined by:
$$B'_t=\int_0^t\mathrm{sgn}W'_s dW'_s.$$
Now, going back to the measure $\mathbb P$, if I define
$$\frac{d\mathbb P'}{d\mathbb P} = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \alpha'_s{}^2ds+\int_0^t \alpha'_s dB_s\right)$$ then I can claim that
$$dZ_{t}=dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}dB'_t=dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}(dB_t+\alpha'_t dt)=(1+2\alpha'_t\sqrt{Z_{t}})dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}dB_t.$$
which is actually not a squared Bessel process but a squared reflected Brownian motion...

Comment: Afaik the squared Bessel process has an SDE it solves. Apply Ito to $Z$ and see if you can match to the Bessel terms.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bessel process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_process) is defined as the Euclidean norm of an $n$-dimensional ($n\ge 2$) Brownian motion, $X_t=\|\mathbf{W}_t\|$ and is known to solve the SDE
$$
dX_t=dB_t+\frac{n-1}{2}\frac{1}{X_t}\,dt\tag{1}
$$
where $B$ is a one-dimensional BM. Ito's formula shows that the square of this,
$Y_t=X^2_t$ solves
\begin{align}
dY_t&=2X_t\,dX_t+d\langle X\rangle_t=2\sqrt{Y_t}\,dB_t+(n-1)\,dt+dt\\[2mm]
&=2\sqrt{Y_t}\,dB_t+n\,dt\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Similarly, the $Z_t=(W_t+\alpha_t)^2$ solves
\begin{align}
dZ_t&=2(W_t+\alpha_t)\,d(W_t+\alpha_t)+d\langle W\rangle_t\\[2mm]
&=2(W_t+\alpha_t)\,dW_t+2(W_t+\alpha_t)\,d\alpha_t+dt\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
When we introduce the BM
$$
\widetilde{W}_t=\int_0^t{\rm sgn}(W_s+\alpha_s)\,dW_s
$$
we can write (3) as
\begin{align}
dZ_t&=2\sqrt{Z_t}\,d\widetilde{W}_t+2(W_t+\alpha_t)\,d\alpha_t+dt\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}

- For no choice of $\alpha$ (with bounded variation) the terms in (4) match those in (2).
- Even if they did the $n$ in (2) must be at least $2$ which obstructs the match with the $dt$ term in (3).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it $Z_t=(W_s+\alpha_s)^2$ when I meant $Z_t=\int_0^td(W_s+\alpha_s)^2$, with $\alpha_t$ well-behaved.

Comment: That's the same :) . The integrand is one.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. I was trying to understand what was wrong with me given your answer. I think that you can leave out $d\alpha_t$ or first derive it when you do Itô as a it embeds a time derivative: $\partial Z_t/\partial W_t$,  $\partial^2 Z_t/\partial W_t^2$ and  $\partial Z_t/\partial dt = \partial Z_t/\partial \alpha_t * \partial \alpha_t /dt$. Am I wrong?

Comment: My first bullet point says that we better leave $\alpha$ out. Then (4) is formally equal to (2). This is strictly speaking not a squared Bessel process (since it requires $n\ge 2$) but it is well defined. It is a squared BM.

Comment: Is there something wrong introducing $$dB_{t} =\mathrm{sgn}(W_{t}+\alpha_{t})d(W_{t}+\alpha_{t})$$
$$d\langle B\rangle_{t} =\mathrm{sgn}^{2}(W_{t}+\alpha_{t})dt=dt$$and conclude $$dZ_{t}=dt+2\sqrt{Z_{t}}dB_{t}$$ Meaning that $Z_{t}$ "starts" from $\alpha^2_{t}$?

Comment: Please read about the matter [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/). With this $dB$ there is something wrong. It's quadratic variation maybe $t$ but it is not a martingale, hence, not a BM. What is a $Z$ that "starts" from a moving target $\alpha_t$ ? Lastly, your last $dZ$ equation is as good as the one you got without any $\alpha$ at all. Why do you need that $\alpha$ to begin with?

Comment: My second question is then how do i deal with this staring point if i integrate the solution from 0 to t to get $Z_t$? Is this point actually a final point $\alpha^2_t$ or is it $Z_t$ that depends on $\alpha^2_0$ or the whole path $\int_0^t\alpha^2_s ds$?

Comment: Case closed. I won't answer any more questions about $\alpha$ if you don't tell me why you need it in the first place. OP contains zero context about that.

Comment: I have actually a process that is more complicated. It is an exercise. I have to deal with $W^2_{A_t}+2W_t$, where $A_t=\int_0^t a_s^2ds$. So I came up with a change of clock of the type $W^2_{A_t}+2W_{A_t}/a_{t}$. Completing the square, then I have $W^2_{A_t}+2W_{A_t}/a_t+1/a^2_t=(W_{A_t}+1/a_t)^2$, in other words $(W_t+\alpha_t)^2$

Comment: Seems like we  have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What does that exercise want you to do with $W^2_{A_t}+2W_t\,?$ This calls for an entirely new question.

Comment: Haha, maybe. I see your point about my $B_t$ not being a martingale. It is tricky... New question it shall be.